# Laravel database connection (save data)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

EDIT:

It doesn't return an error, it just doesn't save it in the database.

The monthly route is defined here:

```
 // Registration Routes...
            if ($options['mensalidade'] ?? true) {
               // $this->get('mensalidade', 'Auth\MensalidadeController@showRegistrationForm')->name('mensalidade');
                $this->post('mensalidade', 'Auth\MensalidadeController@mensalidade')->name('mensalidade');
            }
```

Which controller is handling this request?
MensalidadesController.php
it's just below

What data is included when he handles the request?

It sends the Name, Email and Monthly Fees but does not save to the database

---

I want to save three data (name, email and monthly fees), in the monthly fees table.

This is my progress, but it is not sending to the bank:

Where am I going wrong?

auth.php:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'mensalidade' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Mene::class,
        ],
        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

RegistersUsers.php:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

trait RegistersUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    /**
     * Show the application registration form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    /**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        if ($response = $this->registered($request, $user)) {
            return $response;
        }

        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new Response('', 201)
                    : redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }



/**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function mensalidade(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

      

        if ($response = $this->registered($request, $user)) {
            return $response;
        }

        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new Response('', 201)
                    : redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }


    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during registration.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }

    /**
     * The user has been registered.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

MensalidadesController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Mene;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class MensalidadeController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
 */

use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['requerid', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
            'mensalidade' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Mene
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return Mene::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'mensalidade' => $data['mensalidade'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Mene.php

```
<?php

namespace App;


use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Mene as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Mene extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'mensalidade'
    ];


}
```

home.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Dashboard') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    {{ __('You are logged in!') }}

                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('mensalidade') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="mensalidade" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Mensalidade') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="mensalidade" type="string" class="form-control @error('mensalidade') is-invalid @enderror" name="mensalidade" value="{{ old('mensalidade') }}" required>

                                @error('mensalidade')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Registrar') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Please, as much detail as possible. I just want to add these items to the table

Comment: You need to provide more detail. What error are you getting? Where is this route('mensalidade')  route defined? What controller is handling this request? What data is included when it handles the request.

Comment: Sorry. I changed and added the requested information, thanks for the help

Comment: Are you getting into the create method? Log the variables or a random string to see what's getting called and follow that from the controller into the create method. It would help to narrow down where the issue might be.

Comment: First bit of advice never modify a third party dependency. Your mensalidade(Request $request) function should be in that controller not in Laravel's trait. Secondly, please show a dd() of $data in MensalidadesController.php create() function.

Comment: I removed the modification you suggested. I don't know how to proceed to take the test you asked for; I am a layman on the subject and I am too confused. Could you exemplify?